# Consulta MySQL, Group By

Tags: mysql

estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en mysql y lo que pasa es que me genera un error

Error Code : 1111
Invalid use of group function

Alguien sabe que podrìa yo tener mal, ya intente eliminar el group by o cambiar su valor y aun asi no consigo el resultado

La consulta es la siguiente

```
SELECT  
SUM(AVG(info.avance) / COUNT(part.id_part_activ)) AS Suma
FROM info_medicas AS info
INNER JOIN activacion_participantes AS part ON info.id_part_activ = part.id_part_activ
WHERE part.edad <= 18
GROUP BY part.id_part_activ
```

---

Inicialmente tengo una consulta asì, la cual me arroja la siguiente informacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente hago la siguiente consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bien lo que finalmente deseo lograr es sumar todos esos resultados de la segunda consulta (75, 80, 85, 80) y dividirlos entre la cantidad de registros que alojo que en este caso seria entre 4 para de esta forma obtener un promedio final

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Ya he agregado el campo id_part_activ en el select como me indicas, pero sigo sin resolver el problema

Comment: ¿has revisado el enlace que te ha provisto gbianchi?

Comment: Porque tratas de hacer sum de avg / count? toda esa cuenta no tiene logica. Por eso protesta mysql. Que estas tratando de ahcer? avg ya divide por la cantidad de filas, asi que no tiene mucho sentido.. y despues sumar una sola fila (que es lo que devuelve avg) tampoco tiene sentido.. creo que tenes que mostrar tus datos y decirnos que trataste de hacer.

Comment: asi es, he revisado el enlace y ya he trabajado sobre lo que menciona este enlace pero la verdad me genera el mismo problema

Comment: @gbianchi he publicado mi respuesta, explicando la finalidad de lo que trato delograr, espero puedas ayudarme por favor

Comment: @AdrianValenciaVillegas es muy importante que leas los enlaces que te pase en el primer comentario. Las respuestas, son para respuestas!!!! pára agregar informacion a tu pregunta, hay un boton [edit] ;). Igual transforme tu respuesta en una edicion a tu pregunta

Comment: Y otra cosa importante.. el codigo no va como imagen.. porque si no, no se puede copiar.. por ejemplo no puedo copiarlo para ponerlo en una respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tenes aca, es que no podes hacer todo en la misma consulta..

La funcion avg trabaja sobre un set de datos guiados por el group by.. la funcion sum hace lo mismo, como hace mysql para resolver las dos al mismo tiempo? no puede, y por eso tira el error.

Es mas.. fijate que lo que vos queres.. es calcular el avg del avg (que tengo dudas si matematicamente no da el mismo valor que el avg de todo el conjunto, pero bue)

Para lo que vos queres hacer, alcanza con que hagas lo siguiente:

```
select avg(suma) as suma
from
(
    SELECT  
    AVG(info.avance) AS Suma
    FROM info_medicas AS info
    INNER JOIN activacion_participantes AS part ON info.id_part_activ = part.id_part_activ  
    WHERE part.edad <= 18
    GROUP BY part.id_part_activ
)
```

Tu select de afuera, va a ejecutar el avg que vos queres.

Esto se llama subconsultas, usas una consulta como entrada de otra.

Comment: Sabes creo que ha funcionado, ya lo probe y realice cambios y efectivamente cumple con lo que deseaba resolver, te agradezco muchisimo

Comment: de nada.. **LEE LOS ENLACES!!!!** @AdrianValenciaVillegas

Comment: @AdrianValenciaVillegas Si te funcionó la respuesta de gbianchi, deberías marcarla como la respuesta aceptada para que las demás personas que tengan una duda semejante puedan tomarla como referencia principal (más lo la más importante, claro).

Answer (score 0):

El Group by XXX tiene que ir en el SELECT xxx

> SELECT 
>       status FROM
>       orders GROUP BY status;

Proba con

```
  SELECT  
SUM(AVG(info.avance) / COUNT(part.id_part_activ)) AS Suma,
part.id_part_activ
FROM info_medicas AS info
INNER JOIN activacion_participantes AS part ON info.id_part_activ = part.id_part_activ
WHERE part.edad <= 18
GROUP BY part.id_part_activ
```

Comment: no es ese el problema, es la concatenacion de funciones.